# Binding with this in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, native

```
     _onPressButton =(username) =>{
        // alert("bye")
        this.props.navigation.navigator('Loc');
      }

     loginuser = (username, password) =>{

        Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
        success: (user) =>  {
          // Do stuff after successful login.
            // 
            this._onPressButton(username);
            alert("hello")

        },
        error: (user, error) => {
          // The login failed. Check error to see why.
          alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
       });
      }

    render(){
    let { username } = this.state.username;
    return(

        <View style= {styles.container}>
              <TextField
                  inputContainerStyle={{ justifyContent: 'center', marginTop:30,marginLeft:50, marginRight:50, }}
                  inputStyle={{textAlign: 'center',justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'}}
                  titleTextStyle={{ textAlign: 'center',justifyContent: 'center', }}
                  label='Username'
                  value={this.state.username}
                  onChangeText={ (username) => this.setState({ username}) }
              />

              <TextField
                  inputContainerStyle={{ justifyContent: 'center', marginTop:0,marginLeft:50, marginRight:50, }}
                  inputStyle={{textAlign: 'center',justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'}}
                  titleTextStyle={{ textAlign: 'center',justifyContent: 'center', }}
                  label='Password'
                  secureTextEntry={true}
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChangeText={ (password) => this.setState({ password}) }
              />

            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.loginScreenButton}
                   // onPress={() => this._onPressButton()}
                   onPress={() => this.loginuser(this.state.username, this.state.password)}
                  underlayColor='#fff'>
               <Text 
               style={styles.loginText}> Login </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

        </View>
      );
    }
  }
  export default Project = createStackNavigator({
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Loc: { screen: Loc}
});
```

UPDATE

I am able to call _onPressButton() from function loginuser(username,password) using arrow functions '=>' but this.props.navigation.navigator('Loc') is not working.
alert("bye") works okay but this.props.navigation.navigator('Loc'); doesn't execute. Maybe because of binding 'this' . Can someone help me with that?

P.S 'Loc' just another class which renders current location and prints it.

Comment: can you show a call to loginuser function is it using `=>` or as callback ?

Comment: onPress={() => this.loginuser(this.state.username, this.state.password)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use arrow functions for both your class method and the `success`/`error` callbacks to get the `this` value of the enclosing execution context instead. Since you don't use `await` you can skip the `async` keyword as well.

```
loginuser = (username, password) => {
  Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
    success: (user) => {
      // Do stuff after successful login.
      this._secondFunction();
    },
    error: (user, error) => {
      // The login failed. Check error to see why.
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: i made these changes and its working but  instead of this._secondFunction(); i want to use  this.props.navigation.navigator('Loc') "  and it doesn't do anything inside success option

Comment: @sap Alright, that's frustrating. Could you include your entire component and parent component in your question? It will be hard to say what's wrong otherwise.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated the code now!

Comment: @sap Is `success` even run? Try putting a `console.log` or something in there.

Comment: Yeah success runs fine, even _onPress got called after you suggested arrow functions. (alert in onpress () works but navigation doesn't) . Is it a problem using 'this' inside that function?

Comment: @sap `_onPressButton` is also an arrow function, so `this` should be what you expect in there. Should it not be `this.props.navigation.navigate` instead of `this.props.navigation.navigator`?

Comment: Man how can i miss on that! sorry to bother you! So the main thing was using arrow functions! It is working !Thanks a lot for your time